# Child element live.('click') never runs instead Parent div's Click always runs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

In a parent div's `Click` event I return a function that closes my overlay div like below

```
$('div#overlayBackground').click(function() {
            return clicker();
        });
```

the child elements of this div are filled using `.innnerHTML` and on `document.ready()`I give child elements click function like below:

```
$('#CaptionTextArea').live('click', function(e) {
             e.stopPropagation();
        });
```

so that clicking on `TextArea` does not close the overlay. But the child element `click` never runs instead parent div `click` always runs, Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.live()` method binds the event handler at the *document* level. When the event bubbles to the document jQuery then checks if it occurred for the element(s) you specified. So if you have other event handlers bound closer to the element that the event occurred on and those handlers stop event propagation the `.live`-based handler will never be called. If your `clicker()` function returns `false` that would stop propagation.

You could try this instead:

```
$('div#overlayBackground').on("click", "#CaptionTextArea", function(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
}).on("click", function(e) {
    return clicker();
});
```

That is, use the `.on()` method to replace your `.live()` so that the event handler is actually bound to the same parent element as your other click event. jQuery calls event handlers in the order they're bound, so this `.live()` replacement will be called first and you can use [`event.stopImmediatePropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/) to prevent the second one running.

Comment: Good explanation, although I think the OP's problem is a bit different: I assume the `.live` event handler does run, but of course it has no effect on the other event handler because it was executed before the `.live` event handler (i.e. `event.stopPropagation()` is called "too late").

Comment: Good point @FelixKling. I guess I assumed that `clicker()` was returning false which would stop the event propagating up to the `.live` handler, as I mentioned in my answer, but you're right that either way it is too late to try to stop propagation from a `.live` handler. (Fortunately the code I've shown solves the OP's problem anyway since it _does_ prevent the second handler being called by making sure the two handlers get called in the right order.)

Comment: @nnnnnn thanks for answer, I am going to add functions for all my child elements of `div#overlayBackground` in `$('div#overlayBackground').on` its going to be a huge function but I have the freedom to specify type of event unlike `if( e.target.id != 'CaptionTextArea' )` which will only look at target not the type of event of child element generated.

Answer (score 2):

`.live()` is deprecated in the jQuery library, so you shouldn't be using it. One of the reasons for that is that the event has to propagate all the way to the root-level to be handled, so `stopPropagation` is useless there. The *better* solution is to just handle the case in the same parent click handler:

```
$('div#overlayBackground').click( function(e) {
    if( e.target.id != 'CaptionTextArea' )
        return clicker();
});
```

Since `#CaptionTextArea` (a `<textarea>`) won't have any children for the click events to propagated from, that works just fine; in general though, you would want to handle events from its descendants as well:

```
// ignore clicks which originated within #CaptionTextArea
if( $(e.target).closest('#CaptionTextArea').length === 0 )
```

Comment: if live event is deprecated how should one attach events to elements that are created after document.ready()?

Comment: @jaminator Using the method [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) to bind to some existing parent element. An example on how to port is provided in [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: +1 for writing the option that I couldn't be bothered including in my own answer.

Comment: To account for cases where the event originated from within `CaptionTextArea`, you can use `$(e.target).closest('#CaptionTextArea').length === 0`. You are right that `.live` is deprecated, but you can run into the same problem using `.on`. The main problem is that many people don't understand event delegation. The way `.live` works does not really help in this regard though (it's too obscure), so I'm glad it's deprecated ;)

Comment: @FelixKling - Won't `$(e.target).closest('#CaptionTextArea')` find no elements in every case? I thought the `#CaptionTextArea` element was an actual `<textarea>`.

Comment: @nnnnnn: No, `.closest` tests the element itself too. Of course if it is an element which cannot have descendants, testing the ID directly is better :) *edit:* Yes, the ID seems to suggest that it is a `textarea`, I just wanted to point out this generalisation.

Comment: @FelixKling - Ah. Good. I didn't realise that - I've never used `.closest()` for that purpose before, I've only ever used it to get an ancestor.